# PHP how to include everything i type in my textbox to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

i was wondering how can i include everything written on my textbox to be inserted in mysql database

for example:

```
textbox = "{\buildrel{\lim}"
```

but what happens is the **\ (backslash)** remove **'b'** and **'l'** and the data inserted to my database will be

**{uildrelim}** somewhat like this, it might come up removing the **{ }** as well

so is there any techniques or method you can advise? so that **everything i put in my textbox** will be inserted to my database **as it is**.

I found this solution:

i just need to use the `str_replace()` method to replace single `\` with double `\\`

```
$textbox = str_replace('\\\','\\\\\\\',$textbox);
```

where `{\buildrel{\lim}` will be `{\\\buildrel{\\\lim}`

Comment: If you find an answer please post it as an answer. But `str_replace()` is definitely **not** the answer to your problem as it will not properly escape MySQL strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, You dont use str_replace(), you have [`addslashes()`](https://www.php.net/addslashes) and [`stripslashes()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php), those two are the two functions you are looking for.

Changing a string with str_replace functions isnt a smart thing to do. Those functions aren't created with this in mind, the add/striposlashes are. You might forget a character which you needed to str_replace with a slash.

Also, that whole battery of slashes and escaping slashes doesnt make your code very readable :P